# Problems registering Facebook App

Tags: facebook

I am writing a website using which a user would be able to change his status on facebook. Now for this, I have to register my website on facebook. When I go to register my website on Facebook, there are various options like 'MobileApp', 'FacebookApp', 'Website' etc. Can anyone please suggest which one of these is a correct option for me. An article explaining me the same would be useful. Thanks

Saurabh

Answer (score 0):

What sort of app do you want to build? Those options are for configuring the different places your app will be accessed by users.
It sounds from your description that you probably want 'Website' since you said you're building a website.

Answer (score 0):

You have to **Create a New App** from developers.facebook.com .

Then you go **Settings > Basic** and select **App on Facebook** from bottom section.

Enter your "return url" and its done.

Comment: He said he wants to link to a website, not a canvas app